# Finding $P(X+Y=10)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are both of geometric distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I am having difficulty finding $P(X+Y=10)$, given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and both are geometrically distributed:

$$P(X=k)=P(Y=k)=p^k(1-p), \ \ \ k=0,1,2,...$$

I attempted to set $X=10-Y$ and then find $f_x(10-Y)=P(X=10-Y)$, but my answer does not match the solution $11(1-p)^2p^{10}$. Is the method incorrect or am I just making a calculation error?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with $f_x(Y-10)$?

Comment: Ah I meant the probability function for X, so the $P(X=10-Y)$. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method seems fine to me so probably a calculation mistake (I think you want 10-y). $\Sigma_{y=0}^{10}f_y(y)f_x(10-y)=\Sigma p^{10-y}(1-p)p^y(1-p)=11p^{10}(1-p)^2$. You can verify using the fact that the sum of independent geometric rvs is negative binomial.